# ms access - filter chart by multiselect listbox

Tags: ms-access

I would like to filter a chart by a multiselect box in a form. the chart is based on a query showing

```
Transportation costs: headers: Route; FrightPrice; Toll; HandlingCosts; ..
```

Now I want the form's user to be able to select the wanted Route and Costs. Then a line chart based on the selected route should pop up showing the desired values/lines.

I know how to connect the route to the chart and how to let it pop up by a command button.  The problem I have is to filter the chart showing costs. 
I tried Multiselect Listboxes, radio buttons, checkboxes,.. I could not find a solution.

I think a listbox is the most useful tool for my problem.  But how can I connect the listbox (Row source Type: "field list", multiselect: "simple") to my chart?

Here the VBA code i tried solve my problem with:

```
Private Sub cmdGo_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryPriceFile")

For Each varItem In Me!lstTypeCost.ItemsSelected
    strCriteria = strCriteria & ",'" & Me!lstTypeCost.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
Next varItem

If Len(strCriteria) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "You did not select anything from the list" _
        , vbExclamation, "Nothing to find!"
    Exit Sub

End If

strCriteria = Right(strCriteria, Len(strCriteria) - 1)
strSQL = "SELECT * From tblCost " & _
         "WHERE tblCost IN(" & strCriteria & ");"

qdf.SQL = strSQL
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmChart_MultiSelect"

Set db = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmChart_MultiSelect"

End Sub
```

Comment: So you want multiple parameters on the same field selected in a multi-select listbox? Requires VBA to loop through the listbox and build criteria then sets the chart RowSource property with SQL statement. The criteria can be multiple `OR` operators or a list array used in `IN()` function.

Comment: Thats it i guess. There is no chance of avoiding VBA? (maybe using a macro?) because i do not have much knowledge in VBA.

Comment: Looping a listbox in a macro to build a string and then set RowSource property? I doubt macro can handle looping through listbox selected items and I won't even consider trying. Many examples of VBA for this. Never seen one for macro.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I tried many VBAs which i found online. the problem i always get is that it does not filter my costs. i guess it might be due to my row source type? because no matter what i click it always shows me all types of costs. additionally Access asks me for the parameter value where i have to type in a field list's value (i.e. cost_Freight) which i activated in the listbox.

Comment: If you have code, then edit question to provide it for analysis.